# Dependency of molecular spontaneous emission on the refractive index

Tags: quantum-mechanics, spectroscopy, photon-emission, fluorescence

I am familiar with the following equation for the spontaneous emission rate,
$$
\Gamma_{em}(\omega_{if}) = \frac{\omega_{if}^3}{3\pi\varepsilon_0\hbar c^3} |\mu_{if}|^2\tag{1}
$$
where $\omega_{if}$ is the angular frequency corresponding to the energy difference of the initial and final states $|\phi_i\rangle$ and $|\phi_f\rangle$. This equation holds for a system in vacuum. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spontaneous_emission#Rate_of_spontaneous_emission) states that we get for a system in a homogenous medium with refractive index $n$,
$$
\Gamma_{em}(\omega_{if}) = \frac{n\omega_{if}^3}{3\pi\varepsilon_0\hbar c^3} |\mu_{if}|^2\tag{2}
$$

Does this also transfer to molecules in solution, where the solvent has refractive index $n$ ?

For background, there exists a commonly used equation that is used to estimate the emission rate of molecules in solution from experiments, but that equation has a dependency on the refractive index to the second power $\Gamma_{em}\propto n^2$. The equation is,
$$
1/\tau_0=2.880\times 10^{-9} n^2\langle \tilde \nu_f^{-3}\rangle _{\text{Av}}^{-1}(g_l/g_u)\int \epsilon d \ln \tilde \nu\tag{3}
$$
where $1/\tau_0$ corresponds to $\Gamma_{em}$. This equation is reproduced from the paper,

[S. J. Strickler and Robert A. Berg , "Relationship between Absorption Intensity and Fluorescence Lifetime of Molecules", The Journal of Chemical Physics 37, 814-822 (1962)](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.1733166)

I do not understand why the dependency on $n$ is different and more generally how to derive the proper dependency on $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of these seem to be consistent at least within the many approximations. The Einstein $A$ and $B$ coefficients
were originally for transitions for a single electromagnetic mode.
That is a particular $\vec k$ vector and polarization. This would correspond
to the Fermi's golden rule transition rate
\begin{equation}
\Gamma_{i\rightarrow f} =
\frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |\langle i|V|f\rangle|^2 \delta(E_f -E_i)
\end{equation}
and is the $K|M(0)|^2$ term in Strickler and Berg paper.
The perturbation $V$ is proportional to $\vec p\cdot \vec A$
where $\vec A$ is the vector potential operator, and has a factor of $n^{-1}$,
when you quantize Maxwell's equations in a medium with index of refraction
$n$ over all space.
When you sum over all possible photon states you integrate the $\Gamma$ above
over $d^3k$ which is an angular integration over the photon
direction and changing the magnitude integration to frequency,
$k^2 dk = \frac{n^3}{c^3} \omega^2 d\omega$.
The $n^3$ from this integral and the $n^{-2}$ from the matrix element
give the overal $n$ factor for the total transition rate. You can also
see this same result in classical electromagnetism.

All of the $B$ terms in the Strickler and Berg paper
are proportional to the Fermi's golden rule equation above so they
are proportional to $n^{-2}$. The extinction coefficient is then
proportional to $n^{-1}$, and multiplying by $n^2$ on the left
side of their equation gives their $A$ proportional to $n$.